# What does 0x22e4 mean in php exactly?

Tags: php, numbers

It returns 8932.

So the e4 is the exponential right? but i don't know what the 0x means

And so i don't even know how to google it, sorry!

Malthe

Comment: `0x` means a hex value. `0x22e4` is hex value `22e4`, which is decimal `8932`

Comment: `0x22e4` is the heximal value for the decimal value `8932` (most likely in use for error reporting being `E_PARSE | E_CORE_WARNING | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_COMPILE_WARNING | E_USER_WARNING | E_DEPRECATED`). In binary it'd be `10001011100100`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Comment: It means it is a hexadecimal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hexadecimal value: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), this can be represented in what most people are used to (decimal representation). This is value is an integer in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

0x means that its hexadecimal number notation. 
In decimal notation it's 8932.

You can check it [here](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter). Print 22e4 in left field and press "Convert".